# How to make a scrollpane adjust to its content?

Tags: scrollview, smalltalk, squeak

I am trying to display a `Morph` that can grow and shrink while it is displayed. In order not to risk that the `Morph` grows out of it's window, I would like to put it in a `ScrollPane` so that it can be scrolled if it gets too large for the window. As an example:

```
rows := Morph new


layoutPolicy: TableLayout new;
    listDirection: #topToBottom;
    color: Color white.
sp := ScrollPane new
    extent: 100@100.
sp scroller addMorph: rows.

rows addMorphBack: (RectangleMorph new color: Color red).
rows addMorphBack: (RectangleMorph new color: Color blue).
sp openInWindow.
rows addMorphBack: (RectangleMorph new color: Color green).
```

My problem is that in this example the green rectangle does not fit in the window anymore, but no scrollbar is shown. If the last two lines of code are switched, I do get a scrollbar.

Therefore my question: Is there a way to let a `ScrollPane` know that the `Morph` in it's scroller has increased?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was about to answer the same as [aka.nice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396822/aka-nice)
But it does not always show the right scrollbar.
It seems

```
sp setScrollDeltas.
```

Does the same as `hideOrShowScrollBars` and a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that just sending one message to the ScrollPane will do the trick:

```
sp hideOrShowScrollBars.
```

I first tried to inform the morph about layout changes `rows layoutChanged.` without success.

Then, in order to discover the trick, I browsed all senders of `scroller` message (select scroller in a text pane and hit alt+n ctrl+n or cmd+n depending on platform), and all access to `scroller` instance variable within `ScrollPane` (browse implementors of scroller with alt+m, then select the inst var in ScrollPane>>scroller method and press alt/ctrl/cmd+shift+n, or do the same from the browser `ScrollPane browse`) until I found a reasonnable message send.

Comment: I tried this (just added it after I inserted the green rectangle) and I do get a scrollbar, but I don't seem to be able to scroll...

Comment: @MrTsjolder then it's an invitation to explore a bit more, or just follow answer from Nicolai hess